# array numpy object oriented programming for loop PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, oop

I'm learning oop with array and doing the following program count of an array, but the instance doesn´t the iteration for loop

```
import numpy as np

class arr():
    
    def __init__(self):
       self.arr1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]])
       self.arr1 = self.arr1.reshape(-1)
           
    def cont(self):
        c = 0
        for i in self.arr1:
            if self.arr1[i] > 6:
                c += 1
        return c

rp = arr()
print(rp.cont)
```

Comment: As @jjPark stated, you are printing the function object by using `print(rp.cont)`. To call the function, append parentheses like so: `print(rp.cont())`.

(As a slightly pedantic sidenote; in Python it is common to write class names in [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case), functions/variables/methods/attributes in [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), and constants in SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `rp = arr() print(rp.cont)` to

```py
rp = arr()
print(rp.cont())
```